# Does c# save the length of the array in a buffer value, or it's preferable to do it personally?

Tags: c#

For the sake of curiosity. Does c# save the length of the array in a buffer value, or it's preferable to do it personally?

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

a)

```
int x = numbers.length

for (i = 0; i < x, i++) {}
```

b)

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {}
```

I don't remember seeing one piece of code using "a)" in c#, so either coders don't bother, either c# does the optimization.

I saw that for javascript.

Comment: I never think about it, IMHO using directly is more proper than assigning it to a variable.